# Maybe type implementation

Tags: c++, optional

This supposed to implement a `Maybe` type that can either hold a value `T` or "nothing". It's designed to work well with vectors (that's why I take extra care to noexcept constructors whenever possible). I'm governing the actual data with `::std::aligned_storage`. Note: The `just` member function is a reference to the Haskell `Maybe` data-constructor `Just`.

Did I miss anything?

```
#pragma once

#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

namespace ads {
  template <typename T>
  class Maybe {
    public:
      typedef typename ::std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T),alignof(T)>::type storage_type;
      typedef T value_type;
    private:
      storage_type data;
      bool is_valid;
      inline T* ptr() {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data);
      }
      inline T const* ptr() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&data);
      }
    public:
      Maybe() noexcept : data(), is_valid(false) {}
      template <typename U>
      Maybe(U&& v) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) : data(), is_valid(false) {
        create(::std::forward<U>(v));
      }
      Maybe(Maybe const& from) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value) : data(), is_valid(false) {
        if (from.is_valid)
          create(*from.ptr());
      }
      Maybe(Maybe&& from) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) : data(), is_valid(false) {
        if (from.is_valid)
          create(::std::move(*from.ptr()));
      }
      template <typename U>
      Maybe& operator=(U&& v) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_assignable<T,U>::value) {
        create(::std::forward<U>(v));
        return *this;
      }
      Maybe& operator=(Maybe const& from) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_assignable<T,T>::value) {
        if (from.is_valid) {
          create(*from.ptr());
        } else {
          destroy();
        }
        return *this;
      }
      Maybe& operator=(Maybe&& from) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_assignable<T,T>::value) {
        if (from.is_valid) {
          create(::std::move(*from.ptr()));
        } else {
          destroy();
        }
        return *this;
      }
      ~Maybe() noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value) {
        destroy();
      }

      bool valid() const noexcept {
        return is_valid;
      }
      operator T&() noexcept {
        return *ptr();
      }
      operator T const&() const noexcept {
        return *ptr();
      }
      T& just() noexcept {
        return *ptr();
      }
      T const& just() const noexcept {
        return *ptr();
      }

      template <typename U>
      void create(U&& v) noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value && ::std::is_nothrow_assignable<T,U>::value){
        if (is_valid) {
          *ptr() = ::std::forward<U>(v);
        } else {
          new(&data) T(::std::forward<U>(v));
          is_valid = true;
        }
      }
      void destroy() noexcept(::std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value) {
        if (is_valid) {
          ptr()->~T();
          is_valid = false;
        }
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: Maybe is a long forgotten name of the `std::optional`. I would advocate that optional is much better name rather than Maybe. Maybe sounds rather humorous.

Comment: Hmpf, okay, at least I learned something, here :)

Answer (score 2):

**Creating holes in the type system:**

`operator T&` and it's const sibling is probably very undesirable conversion. Why, then, `std::string` doesn't have `operator const char*()`? The answer is a type system. It meant to be explicit. `std::optional` uses overloading of `operator*()` and `operator->()`.

**Don't pay for what you don't use:**

I would expect constructor to not check for `is_valid` of itself, because it is obvious (you're calling `create()` from constructor, which does check for validity). In most cases this won't make a difference, but you still should strive for perfection.

**Missing features:**

- swap
- comparison operators
- emplace
- `value_or`, which is I think the most useful. Returns provided default value if there optional is not initialized yet.
- one function that throws when the optional is not initialized yet. `just()` is a great candidate.

**Style:**

You could enter a newline in some places where the line is long.

I think that calling global `std` might be somewhat restricting. It is arguable, though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

The bug however, I do not see. In case the object is valid, then I simply assign the new one, if it isn't I don't need destroying. Where would you add a call to `destroy()`?

Comment: Further note: If I have T = vector<U>, then destroying and recreating it, guarantees a malloc, however, that malloc can be saved, when I give the vector a chance to reuse the already allocated storage by simply using the assignment operator.

Comment: @bitmask, you're right. Ive got confused by its name. Not a good one

Comment: I considered `create_assign` but decided it was a quite mouth full :)